# Authentication issue in laravel using SQLite

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, authentication

I use a SQLite database instead of MySQL for authentication on my Laravel app. The registration works perfectly, but the login does not work correctly.

I get the following error:

> These credentials do not match our records.

Please, help me to solve it!

Comment: How are you storing the `users`? Please, provide that part of the code. Also, it would be helpful to know the model and migration related to the `user`.

Answer (score 0):

When you register a new user, the password about to be stored must be encrypted with the `bcrypt()` helper, such as `bcryp($request->password)`.

Otherwise the credentials will not match during login time.

Also, if you did not use the `users` migration packed with Laravel, the password field must be a minimum of 64 characters in lenght.

Comment: i used migration packed with laravel and i use bcrypt() for hashing password but it does not  work !

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your User model

```
  /**
 * Hash password by bcrypt before save in database.
 *
 * @param type $password
 */
public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
{
    if (isset($password)) {
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

everything is working but you have to ensure that
your SQLite DB is not open somewhere else
if it will open in DB browser or any other such type of tool just close that and try again later
will work fine